# Service modules_dep on CentOS 6.3

Tags: configuration, service, daemon, centos6.2

I'm trying to determine the minimum services for correct server operation and I am getting annoyed by the modules_dep daemon.

What is this service used for?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: `ps ax` output

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1   ?        Ss     0:00 init
2   ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd/206286]
3   ?        S      0:00 [khelper/2062867]
4   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
5   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
6   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
7   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
8   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
9   ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
10  ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
11  ?        S      0:00 [rpciod/2062867/]
12  ?        S      0:00 [nfsiod/2062867]
135 ?        S<s    0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
429 ?        Sl     0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
443 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
450 ?        Ss     0:00 crond
556 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
561 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
589 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

`wich modules_dep` output `/usr/bin/which: no modules_dep in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)`

But the daemon is there
`chkconfig --list | grep modules_dep`

```
modules_dep     0:desactivado   1:desactivado   2:activo        3:activo        4:activo        5:activo        6:desactivado
```

It's a VPS from Strato.

Comment: I've never heard of this daemon and quick googling for "module_dep" shows your question on SF as a result #1, could you please provide more details like `ps ax` and `which module_dep`, etc?

Comment: I've been googling for a long time and I am not getting any clue about this. And the correct name is modules_dep, I forgot the 's'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this looks like a one-time bootup script, not a daemon. So it does not consume resources after bootup, nothing to worry about. I guess you can browse its source code at `/etc/init.d/modules_dep`. I can't find it in standard CentOS install so it should be custom.

Comment: Yes!! It's a small script that fixes module.dep for iptables. Thank you! I should start looking at `/etc/init.d/` folder. My fault.